# Get the email/ SNS notification once error criteria matched in kibana

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

I am using ELK stack for log management in production and  I would like to be notified when there is an error, I managed to do with logstash using email output plugin. But I like to do with kibana or elacticsearch. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try using watcher in elasticsearch instead of using logstash email output plugin. which helps to send email notification  once the error criteria is matched.